# Tradingview Pine Script to manually input horizontal price levels

Tags: tradingview-api

I'm trying to create a simple script to manually plot 5 horizontal price levels for SpotGamma levels(Key Gamma, Key Delta, Put Wall, Call Wall, and Hedge Wall).

I'm not a coder but I've done well in the past taking existing code for another study and tweaking it for my purposes.

Really just need the ability to change line style, make it extend all the way to the right, and to remove the colon on the label.

I have a script for this in ToS but I'm moving away from charting on ToS and on to TradingView.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the current code I'm working with:

```
study(" ", shorttitle="", overlay = true)

//Levels

c_level1 = input(1, "KEY GAMMA", type=input.float)
c_level2 = input(1, "KEY DELTA", type=input.float)
c_level3 = input(1, "HEDGE WALL", type=input.float)
c_level4 = input(1, "CALL WALL", type=input.float)
c_level5 = input(1, "PUT WALL", type=input.float)

// Levels

plot(c_level1, title = "KEY GAMMA", color = #007bff, linewidth = 2)
plot(c_level2, title = "KEY DELTA", color = #f2ff00, linewidth = 2)
plot(c_level3, title = "HEDGE WALL", color = #ff00a2, linewidth = 2)
plot(c_level4, title = "CALL WALL", color = #00ff08, linewidth = 2)
plot(c_level5, title = "PUT WALL", color = #ff0000, linewidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hline` instead of `plot` to draw extended lines.

Here is a Pine v5 version of your script:

```js
//@version=5

indicator("hlines", overlay = true)

// Inputs

c_level1 = input.float(20000, "KEY GAMMA")
c_level2 = input.float(22000, "KEY DELTA")
c_level3 = input.float(24000, "HEDGE WALL")
c_level4 = input.float(26000, "CALL WALL")
c_level5 = input.float(28000, "PUT WALL")

// Plots

hline(c_level1, title = "KEY GAMMA", color = #007bff, linewidth = 2, linestyle = hline.style_solid)
hline(c_level2, title = "KEY DELTA", color = #f2ff00, linewidth = 2, linestyle = hline.style_solid)
hline(c_level3, title = "HEDGE WALL", color = #ff00a2, linewidth = 2, linestyle = hline.style_solid)
hline(c_level4, title = "CALL WALL", color = #00ff08, linewidth = 2, linestyle = hline.style_solid)
hline(c_level5, title = "PUT WALL", color = #ff0000, linewidth = 2, linestyle = hline.style_solid)
```

[image: View Screenshot]

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow's image upload feature to include images.